# What meter are "I lik the bred" poems in?

Tags: poetry, meter, sam-garland

I'm trying to determine the meter of ["i lik the bred" poems](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-lik-the-bred):

> "i lik the bred" is a series of short poems about a domesticated cow written by British author Sam Garland, better known by his Reddit handle Poem_for_your_sprog

The original poem

> my name is Cow,
> and wen its nite,
> or wen the moon
> is shiyning brite,
> and all the men
> haf gon to bed -
> i stay up late.
> i lik the bred.

I think it's an alternating stress pattern, but I don't know much about poetry. Perhaps it's iambic tetrameter? But I would like to know for certain.

Comment: If anyone's looking for more of those: https://www.reddit.com/r/ilikthebred/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a very simple type of poetic metre, [iambic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry)) [dimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimeter). Each line consists of just two feet, and each foot consists of an unstressed syllable followed by a stressed syllable:

> my **name** is **Cow**,
> and **wen** its **nite**,
> or **wen** the **moon**
> is **shiy**ning **brite**,
> and **all** the **men**
> haf **gon** to bed -
> i **stay** up **late**.
> i **lik** the **bred**.

Wikipedia's [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry)#Dimeter) of iambic dimeter is Robert Frost's ["Dust of Snow"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44262/dust-of-snow), although not every line is four syllables:

> The way a crow
> Shook down on me
> The dust of snow
> From a hemlock tree
>
> Has given my heart
> A change of mood
> And saved some part
> Of a day I had rued.

You can see that the rhythm of the four-syllable lines in this poem is the same as in the one that you're asking about.

Comment: Ah brilliant, I had gotten, syllables, feet and meter mixed up it seems.

Comment: It's not easy to find examples of iambic dimeter! Robert Herrick's "[To the Lark](https://www.bartleby.com/337/389.html)" is another.

Comment: @GarethRees Lullabies or nursery rhymes might be a place to look? It's such a simple metre, maybe suitable for children's poems.

Comment: another important aspect of the bredlik form is that it is 2 verses of 4 lines, in an ABCB rhyme-scheme. This rhyme scheme actually suggests the bredlik, unlike Dust of Snow, may be better analysed as a pair of rhyming couplets in iambic tetrameter, with a caesura in the middle of each line (marked in the typesetting with a linebreak)